# Different outputs of two programs converting a number to binary

Tags: c++

Program to convert a number to binary number

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    system("cls");
    long Dec,Rem,Bin=0;
    int i=1;
    cout<<"Enter Dec number::";
    cin>>Dec;
    do
    {
        Rem=Dec%2;
        Bin = Bin + Rem*i;
        Dec=Dec/2;
        i*=10;
    }while(Dec>0);
    cout<<endl<<Bin;
    return 0;
}
```

Program to convert a number to binary number

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    system("cls");
    long Dec,Rem,Bin=0;
    int i=0;
    cout<<"Enter Dec number::";
    cin>>Dec;
    do
    {
        Rem=Dec%2;
        Bin = Bin + Rem*pow(10,i);
        Dec=Dec/2;
        i++;
    }while(Dec>0);
    cout<<endl<<Bin;
    return 0;
}
```

The two programs give different results but logic is same. Don't know what is the problem and can't figure it out. (#'s are written so it's not the mistake.)

Comment: I expect `pow` is the culprit, floating pint precision is probably messing it up.

Comment: That's not the problem as I tried to use pow function in to check if it works fine or not. And believe me that 10^2 gave me the answer 14. I am using codeblocks but now I have tried Turbo C++ and it works fine. I think that's the problem of codeblocks as pow() function is not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The function pow returns a double value. The problem might be that it is being used along with long integers in the same sentence in your second snippet. Try changing this line to:

```
Bin = Bin + Rem*((long) pow(10,i));
```

Comment: Nope same problem. But ran the same code in Turbo C++ (In dosbox , currently having some other problems in dosbox) and the program ran fine with correct output. I ran the code in codeblocks and it was givving me wrong outputs.